# Cannot re-enable password requirement for login to my account after disabling it. (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, login, password

Yesterday I temporarily took the password requirement off my login account (the only account on the machine). I then later tried to re-enable it. The password took (it works when I use `sudo` for instance), but it is not required to log in, even though I have checked that option in user settings. How do I make the password required again for login access?

I should also note that the lock screen isn't working, it appears to immediately lock then unlock.

I have tried setting it to no password, then setting a password again.

I recently upgraded to 14.04 from Precise.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this myself. Even though I had set "Automatic Login" to off and had set a user password in **System Settings -> User Accounts**, it had failed to properly set the flags in `/etc/gshadow` and `/etc/group`. To check and see if it is set properly, do in terminal:

```
sudo grep nopasswd /etc/gshadow
```

which should return something like:

```
nopasswdlogin:!::
```

and

```
sudo grep nopasswd /etc/group
```

returning:

```
nopasswdlogin:x:112:
```

Instead, mine looked like:

```
nopasswdlogin:!::josh
nopasswdlogin:x:112:josh
```

if you see user names at the end of these lines, then you need to remove them. Any user names on these lines indicate that user can login in without a password. To remove them, just open the files in gedit and delete ONLY the user names you want to require passwords of. You can open them with:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/gshadow
gksudo gedit /etc/group
```

Once you delete the user names, save the files and reboot. Done!